# Cherrypy session timeout on browser closed?

Tags: python, cherrypy

In cherrypy is there a configuration option so that sessions do not have a "timeout", or if they do, expire immediately when the browser is closed? Right now tools.sessions.on is true and tools.sessions.timeout is 60 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't be completely sure about any option, but this are some possibilities.

1. Listen for an [beforeunload event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser), and make a final request to the server to invalidate the session.
2. Have a very short expiration time on the sessions and a recurrent call to the server via ajax just to keep alive the session while the page is alive. This could cost you a LOT of requests, but will invalidate the session when the user closes the webpage.
3. Pass your state via POST requests, but that is a bad idea a painful one that is usually used on the bank pages.

There is more information related on the docs [here](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/basics.html?#using-sessions) and [here](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.lib.html?#module-cherrypy.lib.sessions).

Answer (score 0):

Set `tools.sessions.persistent` to `False`